# Using || in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

This is only sample code.My point is to make: 'If Hello OR foo word is found, do something'.But while loop does not react, even if both strings are in `text`.If I use only one condition without || while loop does what I expect.How cant I fix this? Thank you!

```
public void start(){
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.yahoo.com").get();
String text=doc.text();

while(!text.contains("Hello")||!text.contains("foo"))
    System.out.println("Not found.");
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean to use `&&`...

Comment: You absolutely need to change text ***within the loop***, else all is lost and your loop risks never ending. If you're already doing this, then please show us and avoid posting sort-of, kind-of code. Post real code so we can understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some operator precendence issues.

Right now, you're saying if text doesn't contain hello OR it doesn't contain foo do the loop; Use

```
while(!text.contains("Hello")&&!text.contains("foo"))
```

instead. This means "if text doesn't contain hello AND doesn't contain foo repeatedly flood System.out with "not found" until the user kills your program or the JVM dies".

Answer (score 3):

You should change your code as follows

```
while(!text.contains("Hello")&&!text.contains("foo"))
    System.out.println("Not found.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
while(!(text.contains("Hello") || text.contains("foo"))){...}
```

Maybe it's what you were trying to do above.